# Is it possible to apply if-else in django base.html?

Tags: django

My all pages are inheriting from base.html file. However I want my about page to be slightly different.
Majority of the pages are having

```
<main role="main" class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div>
          {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                    {{ message }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
          
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
              </ul>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

But about page I want the above code of block like

```
<main role="main" class="container">

         <div>
          {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                    {{ message }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
          
          </div>
</main>
```

So is there a way the second block of code is only executed when the page is "about.html"
else the first block should be executed.

I can do these changes if I do not inherit about from base.html, but then I will be repeating a lot of lines of code. That is why I am looking for another approach

**EDIT**
wondering if something like "{% if url == 'blog-about' %}" exists

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the sidebar to not appear, you can create another html file called sidebar.html and insert the sidebar code, and another html file called message.html and insert the message template.

Then include this tag in all of your pages `{% include sidebar.html %}` and `{% include message.html %}` and leave it for your about.html.

Comment: If I do that it would affect the design of the website. As both messages and sidebar are supposed to be parallel

Comment: I wonder if something like "{% if url == 'blog-about' %}" exsists

Comment: They will be parallel just try it, works a lot for me